# PHP curl returning blank

Tags: php, curl, oauth

hi i am trying to implement the oauth protocol and have manged to get an authorization code,however when requesting a token the curl request i make returns blank.

heres the code i have so far

```
<?php
$code=$_GET["code"];
//URL of targeted site  
$baseurl = "http://okowsc.co.uk/oauth/request_token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENTHERE&client_secret=80e294010d50bc71c04b&code=";
$url="$baseurl" . "$code";
print "$url";

 $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://okowsc.co.uk/oauth/request_token");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    print "$result";

//$returnValue = json_decode('{"access_token":"1e36f6fd77f2f667099ef8f9a0bd332ca4b97831","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"bearer","scope":"","refresh_token":"d23dca2981dd11669501a0a3d2a5d00ef0f51c75"}', true);
$returnValue = json_decode($output, true);
//print_r ($returnValue);
//echo $returnValue[key($returnValue)];
//echo $returnValue[key($returnValue)];
//echo $returnValue[key($returnValue)];
echo $returnValue[key($returnValue)];
?>
```

the request token page works when entered into a browser it should return 
    {"access_token":"***********","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"bearer","scope":"","refresh_token":"****************"}"
(stared out as its an oauth token)
thanks for any  answers

Comment: Try this instead, I got an output from it `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://okowsc.co.uk");` just not sure of the expected result.

Comment: thats weird,it can get the homepage but not /oauth/request_token just checked again loading the same url curl is trying to access(i print it out for debug) in the browser gives me the access&refresh tokens?

Comment: am not sure how to fix that actually, I only took out what I figured could give results. I'm not well-versed in CURL

Comment: neither am i,once i sort out oauth login,i have no further need of curl in this project,anyone else with ideas let me know please,extra thanks in advance